# Nené, nenê e neném

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, origem

Em Portugal, diz-se e escreve-se **nené**, e, no Brasil, escreve-se **neném** e **nenê**, sendo, pela minha experiência, a primeira forma a mais comum.

Daí vieram-me duas perguntas:

- A pronúncia fechada da última sílaba de **nenê** surgiu por conta de alguns imigrantes?
- Qual é a origem do ***m*** de **neném**?

Comment: Eu acho que em Portugal nem se costuma usar a palavra...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As variantes ***nené*** e ***neném*** já existiam antes de 1840; ***nenê***, provavelmente também, e antes de 1860 existia de certeza. Isto é demasiado cedo para a imigração não portuguesa para o Brasil ter tido alguma influência. Se os africanos ou índios tiveram alguma influência, é que eu já não sei dizer. Esta variação entre Portugal e Brasil tem paralelos noutras palavras, e portanto não é de estranhar. Vou agora comprovar o que disse, começando com a antiguidade das três variantes.

### Nené

É a única variante em Portugal. Hoje pode ser rara, mas vem nos dicionários publicados em Portugal desde 1831 (“Menino pequenino”, [Moraes Silva](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lwxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA356&lpg=PA356&dq=%22nen%C3%A9%20s%20m%20menino%20pequenino%22&source=bl&ots=RgvcFPqJCA&sig=ACfU3U0zkxsl62zcmNetVc5ZGq2n3Q1WJQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwlZv3z9rjAhV0oFwKHa1lBscQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nen%C3%A9%20s%20m%20menino%20pequenino%22&f=false)). Aparece também nalgumas publicações portuguesas (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> […] chama,
> *Imoralmente* — **néné**,
> A uma creança de mamma”
> [*O Panorama*, Lisboa, 1855.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fO1GAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA230&dq=Nen%C3%A9&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI0avwgrPRAhVEz2MKHQRnCoY4kAMQ6AEIjQIwJA#v=onepage&q=Nen%C3%A9&f=false)

> [… e]m ella tendo o primeiro **néné**, baptisado de grátis
> [Luís de Araújo, *A Baroneza dos Dentes*, Lisboa, 1872.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=w0tBAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA6&dq=Nen%C3%A9&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI0avwgrPRAhVEz2MKHQRnCoY4kAMQ6AEIsQEwFw#v=onepage&q=Nen%C3%A9&f=false)

Aparece também no Brasil no século XIX:

> […] quando tendo-me em seu collo, embalando-me, dizião «olhem o **néné** como é tão bonitinho,»
> [*O Novo Domingueiro*, Rio de Janeiro, 1847.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=717410&pesq=nene&pasta=ano%20184)

> [Ó] **nené** foge que lá vem o tutu !
> [*Diário do Rio de Janeiro*, 1856.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=nene%20foge&pasta=ano%20185)

### Neném

Esta variante aparece já em 1830. Grafava-se sem acento (tal como *tambem*). Nos segundo e terceiro exemplos, refere-se depreciativamente a adultos.

> […] quando se fala com hum menino, dizem — as nossas amas **nenem** — quer papá, quer fazer piche &c.
> [*O Amigo do Povo*, Pernambuco, 1830.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=815861&pesq=nenem&pasta=ano%20183)

> […] todos os que não quizerão mamar por cauza do tutu **nenem**, restauração serão seguros, e sentar-se-lhes-ha praça na Brigada
> [*Diário do Rio de Janeiro*, 1833.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=tutu%20nenem&pasta=ano%20183)

> — Olhem como é tolo o **nenem**, diz Demar, toma o mais bonito, e eu se rasgar as minhas calças, hei de ficar só com as cinzentas que já estão cheias de nodoas.
> [*Jornal do Commercio*, Rio de Janeiro, 1842.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_03&pesq=nenem&pasta=ano%20184)

> É talvez um baptizado
> De **nênem** afortunado
> [*O Grito Nacional*, Rio de Janeiro, 1853.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=341185&pesq=nenem&pasta=ano%20185)

### Nenê

Indubitavelmente como ’criancinha’, encontrei só a partir de 1858, mas já existia em 1834 como alcunha:

> Assistimos ao casamento e tú serás o padrinho do primeiro **nenê**.
> [*Diario do Rio de Janeiro*, 1858.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=primeiro%20nene&pasta=ano%20185)

> […] hum individuo conhecido por Côcô, e outro por **nênê**
> [*Diario do Rio de Janeiro*, 1834.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=por%20nene&pasta=ano%20183)

Por esta altura no Brasil, as outras variantes também servem de alcunha: temos um Joaquim da Silva conhecido por [Nené (Rio de Janeiro, 1833)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=749443&pesq=alcunha%20nene&pasta=ano%20183), uma [sinhá Nenem (Espírito Santo, 1850)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=218235&pesq=nenem&pasta=ano%20185) e um Antonio José de Souza, conhecido por [Antonio Onofre Nenem, (Pernambuco, 1855)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=029033_03&pesq=onofre%20nenem&pasta=ano%20185). *Nené* era também nome oficial: [Manoel Rodrigues Nené (Rio Grande do Sul, 1839)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=718742&pesq=nene&pasta=ano%20183) e [José Cupertino de Abreu Nené (Rio de Janeiro, 1841)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=abreu%20nene&pasta=ano%20184).

### Paralelos com outras palavras

Os dois ee têm timbre aberto em *nené* e fechado em *nenê*, daí encontrar-se no passado *néné* e *nênê*. Ora esta oposição entre timbre aberto em Portugal e fechado no Brasil encontra paralelos em palavras como *g**é**nero-g**ê**nero, ef**é**mero-ef**ê**mero, c**ó**nico-c**ô**nico, c**ó**mico-c**ô**mico*, etc., que têm acento agudo em Portugal e circunflexo no Brasil. Segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Nasaliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o),o acento circunflexo destas palavras no Brasil resulta de nasalação que a vogal tónica sofre por causa da consoante nasal **n** ou **m** que se lhe segue, levando isso também ao fechamento do timbre. Em Portugal essa nasalação não ocorre. Este artigo [(“Progressive vowel nasalization in Brazilian Portuguese”)](https://www.academia.edu/20205673/Progressive_vowel_nasalization_in_Brazilian_Portuguese_A_preliminary_analysis) conclui que no Brasil ocorre também nasalação na vogal tónica precedida de **m** ou **n**, como é o caso do segundo **e** de *nenê*. Portanto a oposição entre *nené* em Portugal e *nenê* no Brasil enquadra-se perfeitamente num padrão mais geral das diferenças  fonológicas entre Portugal e Brasil. O caso de *neném* pode ser simplesmente um fortalecimento da nasalação já presente em *nenê*, levando o escritor a sentir necessidade de incluir um **m** final para indicar a nasalação.

Esta nasalação de vogais por via de eme ou ene seguinte foi muito comum na evolução do latim para o português, e também se encontram casos de nasalação por via de eme ou ene anterior. Portanto esta nasalação que presentemente ocorre no português do brasileiro mas não no europeu não é nada de extraordinário no panorama geral da língua portuguesa. Mas alguns historiadores defenderam (segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Nasaliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o)) que ela resultou de influência dos índios.

Answer (score -2):

A palavra *nenê* não existe aqui. O correto para se referenciar a um bebê é ***neném***.

Porém é comum na linguagem informal, as pessoas pronunciarem nenê ao invés de neném, mas essa não é forma correta.

Por conta disso, *nenê* pode ser usado como nome, como: *Nenê de Vila Matilde*.

Comment: Os dicionários [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/nen%C3%AA) e [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/nene%20_1007491.html) não concordam que "não existe". Tem alguma referência para "nenê" ser menos correto do que "neném"? E tem alguma resposta às 2 perguntas originais?

Comment: Eu acho que, na verdade, ambos "nenê" e "neném" são informais. Já ouviu a palavra "neném" ser dita pela mídia? Apenas ouve-se "bebê".

Comment: Nenê, e seus sinônimos neném e bebê: http://www.dicio.com.br/nene/

Answer (score -3):

Os comentários responderam a esta questão.

> A pronúncia fechada da última sílaba de *nenê* surgiu por conta de alguns imigrantes?

Eu acho que em Portugal **nem se costuma usar a palavra**...
só se ouve a palavra ***bebé*** – Jorge B. (Parafraseado)

Ou seja,

A denominação para um "nenê", em Portugal, é ***bebé***

Comment: embora o que escreveste clarifique problemas na pergunta, não responde ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @ANeves e Oak, na verdade não clarifica problema na pergunta. *Nené* já foi usado em Portugal (a palavra *bebé* é mais tardia) e é isso que é relevante para a pergunta.

Answer (score -5):

*Nenê* surgiu no cotidiano da escravidão indígena no Brasil. *Nê* em tupi significa ’feder’ ou ’fedido’. Diferente dos filhos dos indígenas que sempre eram limpos após fazerem suas necessidades, os filhos dos senhores de engenho ficavam envoltos em panos e não eram limpos na mesma hora. Neste contexto, surge a indígena com "nê-nê" (’muito fedido’), avisando a senhora da casa que o bebê estava sujo. Porém, a senhora pensava que aquilo se travava de um elogio.

Comment: Antônio, bem-vindo à comunidade. Isso teria acontecido há 300 ou 400 anos, então é importante dizeres como é que sabes que isso aconteceu. Algum dicionário ou estudo sobre o assunto? Depois, a pergunta é porque é que é *nené* em Portugal e *nenê* ou *nenem* no Brasil.