# Atualmente é incorreto dizer "de grátis"?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, sintaxe, classe-gramatical

Numa resposta sobre uma dúvida da grafia de [*nené/neném/nenê*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/nen%C3%A9-nen%C3%AA-e-nen%C3%A9m)  é citado uma obra de autor português de 1902 ([Luiz D'Araujo Junior, *Por causa d'um algarismo*, 1902](https://books.google.pt/books?id=w0tBAAAAYAAJ&dq=Nen%C3%A9&pg=RA1-PA6#v=onepage&q=%22baptisado%20de%22&f=false)) onde consta:

> Em ella tendo o primeiro néné, baptisado **de gratis**...

Os professores de língua portuguesa no Brasil não cansam de repetir que esta expressão é incorreta, sendo o correto usar "de graça", "grátis", ou "gratuito". Exemplos declarando que é incorreto não faltam na internet, mas sem muitas explicações dos motivos de ser incorreto.

Se é incorreto, o texto de **Luiz D'Araujo Junior** está errado, ou modificações aconteceram na língua que tornaram esta expressão incorreta ? Quais ?

Uma das fontes que aponta como expressão incorreta: [vestibular uol](https://vestibular.uol.com.br/duvidas-de-portugues/ligue-que-ganhara-de-gratis-um-ingresso.htm)

Comment: Eu nem tinha reparado nesse "de grátis"; não me lembro de ter ouvido cá por Portugal. Há no Brasil quem diga? Para haver professores a corrigir...

Comment: @Jacinto. Sim, é uma expressão informal bastante comum.

Comment: Sim há @Jacinto. Alguns o dizem de propósito para soar engraçado, outros o dizem provavelmente por ter aprendido a falar assim. Eu uso às vezes para soar engraçado.

Comment: @Luciano Eu também uso pra soar engraçado. Assim como "é de grátis", também tem "é 0800" :-)

Comment: No texto é "de gratis" e não  "de grátis".  Poderia ser Latim? Ou seja, talvez justificando o uso...?

Answer (score 3):

Parece-me difícil justificar o uso de *de grátis* (nem nunca ouvi sequer tal coisa). Todos os dicionários o dão como adjetivo (=gratuito) e, mais relevante para a pergunta, como advérbio (=gratuitamente).

Já sendo um advérbio, dizer *de grátis* faz tanto sentido como dizer **de gratuitamente*. O complemento de um sintagma preposicional tem de ser um sintagma nominal (ou uma frase). Por exemplo, temos *de repente* (*repente* é um nome), mas apenas *repentinamente* (não **de repentinamente*).

Answer (score 0):

O uso dessa forma é considerado errado atualmente apesar de ser até comum vê-la sendo utilizada no escopo do português coloquial. Porém como o texto é de 1902, para a época era a forma correta, visto que o coloquial era comum e não haviam ainda formalizações bem estruturadas.

Comment: Não creio "de grátis" fosse a forma correta mesmo em 1902. Podes ver que grátis já era classificado como advérbio [nos dicionários antigos (tens links a esses dicionários neste post)](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/resources-for-etymological-research-recursos-para-investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-etimol%C3%B3gica). Quando apresentam exemplos, é sem o "de".

Comment: "*na época o coloquial era comum e não haviam ainda formalizações bem estruturadas*" - Em que você baseia essas afirmações? Elas parecem completamente falsas.

Comment: http://purl.pt/homepage/141/141_132.jpg

Comment: COELHO, Adolfo, 1847-1919
A lingua portugueza : phonologia, etymologia, morphologia e syntaxe / por F. Adolpho Coelho. - Coimbra : Imprensa da Universidade, 1868. - 136 p. ; 21 cm